# Compiling clang-llvm examples

Tags: c++, c, llvm, clang

I am trying to compile the [Hello](http://llvm.org/docs/WritingAnLLVMPass.html#passtype) example in directory `lib/Transforms/Hello`, which is basically a Hello World of LLVM pass, but I get the following error when I try to compile it using *make*.

```
../../../Makefile.common:61: ../../../Makefile.config: No such file or directory
../../../Makefile.common:69: /Makefile.rules: No such file or directory
make: *** No rule to make target `/Makefile.rules'.  Stop.
```

Any idea what is the problem and how to fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you built LLVM + Clang according to instructions, the `Hello` sample should have already been built. Go to `lib/Transforms/Hello` *in the build directory* (where you ran `configure` and then `make`). There should be a `Debug+Asserts` (or whatever configuration you compiled) there. And you can also run `make` from there again.

In general, you always `make` from the build directory, not the source directory. The build directory has all the Makefiles properly set up.

Comment: So this means each time you change code, you need to call make from the top of the tree, which obviously consumes a long time. Isn't there anyway to shorten this building time?

Comment: @MetallicPriest: if you just changed a file or two, it consumes very little time to run `make` from the top of the tree. This is what `make` is for, and most big projects use it.

Comment: Infact now I got it compiled even by calling make from the local directory.

Comment: @MetallicPriest: in the LLVM build dirs you can call `make` from sub-directories as well, yes.